# Django Unique Constraint doesn't Work on creating unique project titles for each user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So I have this project where I have several supervisors that can create projects. I want that for each supervisor they can't make a project with the same title. I tried to use UniqueConstraint but now it's not working. Supervisors can still create a project with the same title. Note: Project's supervisor is automatically assigned to the project creator.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
due_date = models.DateField()
due_time = models.TimeField()
supervisor = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

class Meta:
    constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['title', 'supervisor'], name="unique title")]
    verbose_name = "Project"

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.title) + "-" + str(self.supervisor)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateProjects(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = models.Project
    fields = ['title', 'due_date', 'due_time']
    widgets = {
        'due_date': DateInput()
    }
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/signin")
def create_project(response):
    if response.user.is_staff:
        if response.method == 'POST':
            form = forms.CreateProjects(response.POST, response.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                # save project to db
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.supervisor = response.user
                print(instance.supervisor)
                instance.save()
                return redirect('/dashboard')
        else:
            form = forms.CreateProjects(initial={'supervisor': response.user})
        ctx = {'form': form, 'FullName': response.user.get_full_name}
    else:
        form = "Only Teachers can create projects"
        ctx = {'form': form, 'FullName': response.user.get_full_name}
    return render(response, "create_project.html", ctx)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to define unique on the field.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
```

repeat on any field(s) you want it to be unique.